# A word or phrase for a person who acts or dresses like the weather is going to change suddenly?

Tags: word-choice, translation

In Portuguese, when a person carries an umbrella on a sunny day, we say that this person is "*calling* the rain". When they wear a sweater on a warm day, we say that they are "*calling* the cold [weather]", and so on.

How to express this in English? Are there set ways to make ironic comments about it?

Comment: "What are you, a [*boy scout*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_Motto#Baden-Powell_on_.22Be_Prepared.22)?"

Comment: I think you could say "calling the rain" and people would know exactly what you mean. After all, "called it!" is a rather common exclamation in English.

Comment: "Better to have it and not need it; than need it and not have it."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In American English, we would typically say they were **daring the rain to come** or **daring the cold weather to come**.  For a slightly less aggressive phrase, you can also use **asking for it to rain** or **asking for the cold weather**, which has more of a connotation of ignorant action rather than deliberate provocation.

Because of the somewhat whimsical nature of all of these phrases, in spoken English we will often add the word "just" to the front of the phrase, to indicate that we are emphasizing the exaggeration implicit in the words:

> "Carrying around an umbrella on a sunny day is just *asking* for it to rain!" said Claudia, frowning at her friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is

- A word or phrase for a person who acts or dresses like the weather is going to change suddenly

Then in the content of your question you referred to the person trying to

- do a rain-dance.

Therefore, I am presuming there are two-sides to the coin of your question.

1. You wish to know how to say in English when a person dresses incongruously or inappropriately for the current weather.

   The terms are indeed *incongruous* and *inappropriate*. The dictionary also proposes a rather big word *malapropos*, malaproposly.
2. You wish to know how to say when people dress like they are *doing a rain-dance*, hoping to invite the rain.

   Yes, I've had people tell me "Are you doing a rain dance"?

BTW, I did have an umbrella over me during the hot summers months when I lived in Israel or Texas. No point trying fight the sun by exposing yourself unnecessarily to the risk of skin cancer.

---

malapropos (ˌmælæprəˈpəʊ)

adj

1. of an inappropriate or misapplied nature or kind
   adv
2. in an inappropriate way or manner
   n
3. something inopportune or inappropriate

[from French mal à propos not to the purpose]

*[Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malapropos)*

Comment: https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tba7pmytmmrzi3xgfyoogoj5wlu?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics